# my system can't switch to intel graphics shows LLVM instead ???

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, 18.10

excuse me I'm using a manually installed NVIDIA graphics driver from Geforce official website [image]

when I use prime-select to switch to intel graphics instead of NVIDIA it shows me this and the system can't identify my intel graphics

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

[image]

what exactly should I do to switch to intel graphics

Comment: I don't believe that nvidia-prime works with the upstream blob

Comment: prime-profiles isn't displayed in NVIDIA x server settings app 

and working with command line is more efficient than GUI